# why tcl md5:md5 result is different of md5sum result

Tags: tcl, md5, md5sum

The following tcl code generate the different result than md5sum executable

```
#!/usr/bin/tclsh 

package require md5

puts [md5::md5 -hex "test_string"]
```

the result is:

```
3474851A3410906697EC77337DF7AAE4
```

In UNIX shell:

```
echo "test_string" | md5sum
```

the result is:

```
fd77c0776e992fc96647b3bc220b3adc  -
```

Why the results are different?

Comment: Thanks Juhana, I got the idea from keltar answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
puts [md5::md5 -hex "test_string"]
```

3474851A3410906697EC77337DF7AAE4

```
echo -n "test_string" | md5sum
```

3474851a3410906697ec77337df7aae4  -

So - wrong `echo`, but what's with your tcl? Are you sure you posted correct example?

Comment: You are right , I paste wrong tcl result it is supposed to be 3474851A3410906697EC77337DF7AAE4 , as in your answer. I've updated the question entry. Thanks!